# Why GitHub pull request "back-merges" when resolving conflicts

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

When resolving conflicts in a pull request via Github Editor I always end up with 2 merges instead of one.

Example: I want to merge unsynced changes on master (A) into feature branch

- Create pull request base:feature head:master (B)
- Github detects conflicts
- I resolve them using Github UI editor
- I merge the pull request
- C and D are created (2 merges done here)
- C contains everything merged (as expected)
- D contains the same changes (**not expected**)

and this is how it looks afterwards (P - common parent, A - the change I wanted to propagate into feature branch)

```
P---A----D
 \     /   \
  \---B-----C
```

- C has a comment: "Merge pull request #xyz from master"
- D has a comment: "Merge branch 'feature' into master"

Can anybody say why is the D created? It makes both branches effectively equivalent. I wanted to have all the changes from A reflected in the feature branch.